# Cannot consume Spring REST API with jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, spring, rest, heroku

I wrote simple REST API in Spring Boot and deployed it on Heroku 
( http://books-anzu.herokuapp.com/books/1 )
now I created simple webapp which consumes this API with jQuery, script books.js look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://books-anzu.herokuapp.com/books/1"
}).then(function(data) {
    $('.book-id').append(data.id);
    $('.book-title').append(data.title);
    $('.book-author').append(data.author);
    $('.book-description').append(data.description);
    $('.book-publicationYear').append(data.publicationYear);
    $('.book-numberOfPages').append(data.numberOfPages);
    });
});
```

and html file:
https://pastebin.com/XptrVv4x

output is without data from API... what is wrong with this? I also try to run webapp on springboot with tomcat and output is the same. I was following this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two applications are on different domains(or port,protocol) you need to enable CORS on server side. Check your browser console for this error. You can enable cors with this sample configuration

```
  @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://domain2.com")
                    .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")
                    .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
                    .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
                    .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You consume JSON data, you need to use dataType to tell jQuery you want to parse JSON data :

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

Or you can use `$.getJSON`, more infos : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0):

I've just added @CrossOrigin annotation for my controller class (on server side) and it's solves my problem.

Thanks for all replies.